# HTTP redirects when working with REST APIs

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

One of my very obvious knowledge gaps is HTTP redirects and what role they play when working with AJAX requests and APIs. I've read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) MDN guide on redirects. I know that redirects return a `3xx`status code and provide a `Location` response header. Furthermore, the MDN guide states this:

> When browsers receive a redirect, they immediately load the new URL
> provided in the Location header.

This makes sense to me when dealing with HTML directly (e. g. submitting a form and receiving a redirect after).

When dealing with API's it all becomes a little fuzzy. I've read this [quora post](https://www.quora.com/Do-redirects-in-the-REST-API-make-sense) where most participants say that redirects don't play any role in REST. When I tested this, the browser made a request to the URL provided in the `Location` header but did not navigate to it. Instead, I would just load the HTML response if the location was on the same origin and fail with a CORS error for different origins.

**I'm currently trying to solve this problem:** I send an AJAX payload to an API and want to redirect the user to a different domain (& origin) upon completion. **My question is this:** Do I send back the redirect URL as a payload and navigate the user to the new origin with the `window.location` object (javascript) or can this be handled with a HTTP redirect?

I'd love some help.

Comment: With ajax you need to use js to do page redirects using window.location. Sometimes people use ajax when they could just do a standard form submit and have the server do the redirect

Comment: HTTP requests are always initiated by the client (browser). The client cannot make an XMLHttpRequest request, have the response returned as a `200` with the response data, while in the very same response send a `301`, `302`, `308`. As charlie says, once data is received and processed, the client can make a new request either to the new location or to a redirecting endpoint. But that request should be done via HTTP, not XMLHttpRequest.